# Getting specific headers in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, http-headers

I'm making a simple Node.js app and need to be able to check the Authorization header of a request.  The problem is that all I get in terms of that header is the fact that it's there.  The `headers` property of my request only says `access-control-request-headers : "accept, authorization, content-type"` and nothing else about the content of those headers.  Does Node not look that far into the request?

Answer (score 1):

Those headers *aren't* there.

You're seeing a single header named `Access-Control-Request-Headers`, with a value of `"accept, authorization, content-type"`.

Comment: Ok, so upon closer inspection you're right.  Odd thing is that what I'm sending to my server is a `$.ajax()` request with the `type` set to `"GET"`, yet the request that shows up at the server is an `OPTIONS` type.  No idea why this is happening.